# Limit of double sum: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{-2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sum\limits_{m=k+1}^n\left(\frac{n-2k}{n+2k}\right)^2\frac{n-2m}{n+2m}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Who is so kind to enlighten me about the steps I need to follow? 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{m=k+1}^n\left(\frac{n-2k}{n+2k}\right)^2\frac{n-2m}{n+2m}$$

Comment: :whats source ?

Comment: Convert it to a single sum.  You are showing a relation between k and m.  Use it.  
You might get lucky with someone answering it for you, but unless you show some attempt it is less likely that someone is just going to flat out give you the answer.

Comment: One remark: if $m$ runs from $k+1$...when $k=n$ the second sum has no point i think? Or?

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a Riemann sum:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \left ( \frac{1-\frac{2k}{n}}{1+\frac{2k}{n}}\right)^2 \sum_{m=k+1}^n \frac{1-\frac{2m}{n}}{1+\frac{2m}{n}} = \int_0^1 dx \left (\frac{1-2 x}{1+2 x}\right )^2 \, \int_x^1 dy \frac{1-2 y}{1+2 y}$$

The evaluation of the above integral is straightforward but messy.  The inner integral has an antiderivative

$$\begin{align}\int dy \frac{1-2 y}{1+2 y} &= \int \frac{dy}{1+2 y} - \int dy \frac{2 y}{1+2 y}\\ &= \frac12 \log{(1+2 y)} - \left [y - \frac12 \log{(1+2 y)} \right ]\\ &= \log{(1+2 y)}-y\end{align}$$

The integral is now a single integral when the inner integral is evaluated over its integration limits:

$$\int_0^1 dx \left (\frac{1-2 x}{1+2 x}\right )^2 \left [\log{3} - 1 + x - \log{(1+2 x)} \right ]$$

This integral may be evaluated by substituting $u=1+2 x$, $x=(u-1)/2$, to get

$$\frac12 \int_1^3 du \left (\frac{4}{u^2} - \frac{4}{u}+1\right ) \left [\log{3}-1+\frac{u-1}{2} - \log{u}\right]$$

Now,

$$\begin{align}\frac12 \int_1^3 du \left (\frac{4}{u^2} - \frac{4}{u}+1\right )(\log{3}-1) &= \left(\frac{7}{3}-2 \log{3}\right) ( \log{3}-1) \\ &= -\frac{7}{3} + \frac{13}{3} \log{3} - \log^2{3}\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\frac12 \int_1^3 du \left (\frac{4}{u^2} - \frac{4}{u}+1\right ) \log{u} &= 2 \int_1^3 du \frac{\log{u}}{u^2} - 2 \int_1^3 du \frac{\log{u}}{u} + \frac12 \int_1^3 du \, \log{u} \\ &= 2 \left [ - \frac{\log{u}}{u}\right]_1^3 + 2 \int_1^3 \frac{du}{u^2} - [\log^2{u}]_1^3 + \frac12 [u \log{u}-u]_1^3 \\ &= \frac13 + \frac{5}{6} \log{3} - \log^2{3}\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\frac12 \int_1^3 du \left (\frac{4}{u^2} - \frac{4}{u}+1\right ) \frac{u-1}{2} &= \frac14 \int_1^3 du \left (-\frac{4}{u^2} + \frac{8}{u} - 5+u \right )\\ &= 2 \log{3}-\frac{13}{6}\end{align}$$

Adding the above three results together, I get for the desired limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \left (\frac{n-2 k}{n+2 k} \right )^2 \, \sum_{m=k+1}^n \frac{n-2 m}{n+2 m} = -\log^2{3} + \frac{33}{6} \log{3} - \frac{29}{6}$$

which is about $0.002085$.

Comment: you're great. Thank you.